# mongo db.stats() dbsize is not correct

Tags: mongodb

I set up the topology for the mongo with wiredTiger engine, sharding, repset, here is the experiment, which is interesting.

1. Insert 4002 records, the data size as below , the datasize is bigger that storageSize, which is confusion. Another confusion thing is the totalIndexSize  is even bigger than storageSize.

   ```
   "127.0.0.1:27020" : {
         "db" : "test",
         "collections" : 1,
         "objects" : 4002,
         "avgObjSize" : 51.694902548725636,
         "dataSize" : 206883,
         "storageSize" : 114688,
         "numExtents" : 0,
         "indexes" : 2,
         "indexSize" : 147456,
         "ok" : 1
   ```

2, Remove all the 4005 records, the data size as below, which make sense, the datasize is 0, while the storageSize is the same as previous. Mongo does not free disk after remove document. Confusion thing is the IndexSize is not decreased after data remove.

```
 "127.0.0.1:27020" : {
         "db" : "test",
         "collections" : 1,
         "objects" : 0,
         "avgObjSize" : 0,
         "dataSize" : 0,
         "storageSize" : 114688,
         "numExtents" : 0,
         "indexes" : 2,
         "indexSize" : 147456,
         "ok" : 1
```

3, Adding some 100 records  into db again, it goes to another shard disk(port:27018), before adding, the StorageSize=86016, after inserting, the storageSize=73728, which is smaller than before. Which is confusion. Also the indexSize is smaller after inserting.

```
"127.0.0.1:27018" : {
             "db" : "test",
             "collections" : 1,
             "objects" : 100,
             "avgObjSize" : 52.9,
             "dataSize" : 5290,
             "storageSize" : 73728,
             "numExtents" : 0,
             "indexes" : 2,
             "indexSize" : 65536,
             "ok" : 1
```

4, Adding another 100000 records, it goes to shard port:27020,  again dataSize is bigger than storageSize, and for the shard port:27018, the index size decreased from 65536 to 49152 while there is nothing change in the shard.

```
"127.0.0.1:27018" : {
        "db" : "test",
        "collections" : 1,
        "objects" : 100,
        "avgObjSize" : 52.9,
        "dataSize" : 5290,
        "storageSize" : 24576,
        "numExtents" : 0,
        "indexes" : 2,
        "indexSize" : 49152,
        "ok" : 1
},
"127.0.0.1:27020" : {
        "db" : "test",
        "collections" : 1,
        "objects" : 100000,
        "avgObjSize" : 57.8889,
        "dataSize" : 5788890,
        "storageSize" : 2433024,
        "numExtents" : 0,
        "indexes" : 2,
        "indexSize" : 1765376,
        "ok" : 1
```

Now how can I  trust the mongo status result ? what it the behind logic for this

Answer (score 1):

#### What you seek:

1. The *storageSize* metric is equal to the size (in bytes) of all the data extents in the database. Without compression, this number is larger than dataSize because it includes yet-unused space (in data extents) and space vacated by deleted or moved documents within extents.
   However, **as you are using the WiredTiger storage engine**, data is compressed on the disk and is therefore smaller than the dataSize.
2. When you remove documents, the indexes are **not** removed automatically.See here.
3. The decrease in storage size can again be attribute to the compression of data on disk after you insert new documents.
4. Change in data size: Same as 1.